# Object colours disappear when I turn on 'Texture Solid'

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I have imported a build-set roblox roblox studio into blender. It looks like this:
[image: without texture]

But when I click the textured solid, it looks like this and all of the colours in the background have dissappeared:
[image: with textured solid]

Is there any possible way that the colours in the background (the door & bed) still keep their colour, but also te textures are shown with it?

Answer (score 2):

The colors will appear once you render the picture. I had this same problem.

Go under System Preferences > Input , and look for Emulate Keyboard (turn this on temporarily). Now exit out of that and press 0 on the keyboard. The exterior should go grey and show a frame. use Shift + F to navigate and find your desired camera angle then click Render on the side of the screen in the render settings menu.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to **GLSL** and try **Material mode** instead of **Textures**.
Basicly your background objects **do not** have any textures.
What your see in **Solid mode** is the color of the shader.

I'm not really used to blender render but in **Cycles**:

**Texture Mode:**
Will display the latest selected texture node / Slot.

**Material Mode:**
Tries to display maps mixes properly (allowing texture layering right in Blender's viewport)